# Adding an extra field to drupal 6 comment form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

i need to add one extra "Name" field to the drupal comment form. I implemented this using hook_form_alter. Now the field is coming. I can't control its position. Now it is coming last. I changed the weight , then also it is not affecting.

```
function comment_extra_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
global $user;
$output = '';
   if (!$user->uid) {
    switch ($form_id) {        
          case 'comment_form':
            $form['admin']['name'] = array(
              '#type' => 'textfield',
              '#title' => t('Name'),
              '#weight' => -1,
              '#size' => 60,
              '#maxlength' => 60,
              '#default_value' => $author,

            );

            $output .= comment_render($form);

            break;
    }
    return $output;
}
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this snippet , and read reason for that.**

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  $output = '';
  switch ($form_id) {
   case 'comment_form':
     $form['_author']['#weight'] = -50;
     $form['subject']['#weight'] = -49;
     $form['name'] = array(
     '#type' => 'textfield',
     '#title' => t('Name'),
     '#weight' => -48,
     '#size' => 60,
     '#maxlength' => 60,
     '#default_value' => $user,
     );
     $form['comment_filter']['#weight'] = -47;
     $output .= comment_render($form);
   break;
}
return $output;
}
```

The reason is that : you also need to set weight for other fields as well ,which helps you to set weight of your custom field.

I think above snippet will help you . If further need is require please let me know, will definitely help.